# Flutter google cloud platform or-cbat 15 error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am getting or-cbat 15 error when billing on google cloud platform. How can i solve this. I think it's a problem with google cloud.

Comment: _The OR-CBAT-15 error message means that the issue seemed to be caused by the payment method used. As such, if you want to investigate this issue, is recommended to contact the [Billing Support team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) as they can help you escalating this issue._ More info at [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219092749#comment92).

Comment: To be able to contact the Billing Support team, you have to have a Billing Account, and you can't have a billing account because of OR-CBAT-15 !!!!!!!!

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand why this same STUPID answer have been given to us over and over again!

Comment: please post an update. did you manage to resolve it?